# Symfony Error : RuntimeException Your configuration must have at least one domain

Tags: php, symfony

when I try to access a webpage on my website, I have this error logs :

### (1/1) RuntimeException Your configuration must have at least one domain.

```
in LdapManager.php (line 86)
at LdapManager->__construct(object(Configuration))
in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 2051)
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getLdapTools_LdapManagerService()
in classes.php (line 5406)
at Container->get('ldap_tools.ldap_manager')
in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 2494)
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getProfilerService()
in classes.php (line 5406)
at Container->get('profiler')
in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 2507)
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getProfilerListenerService()
in classes.php (line 5406)
at Container->get('profiler_listener')
in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 733)
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->{closure}()
in classes.php (line 5644)
at EventDispatcher->sortListeners('kernel.exception')
in classes.php (line 5528)
at EventDispatcher->getListeners('kernel.exception')
in classes.php (line 5719)
at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->getListeners('kernel.exception')
in TraceableEventDispatcher.php (line 250)
at TraceableEventDispatcher->preProcess('kernel.exception')
in TraceableEventDispatcher.php (line 139)
at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exception', object(GetResponseForExceptionEvent))
in classes.php (line 7121)
at HttpKernel->handleException(object(FileLoaderLoadException), object(Request), 1)
in classes.php (line 7053)
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
in Kernel.php (line 169)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in app_dev.php (line 29)
```

This is the app_dev.php file :

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup
// for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['1xx.0.0.1','1xx.0.16.163','1xx.0.0.250','1xx.0.0.226','1xx.0.0.233','::1'], true) || PHP_SAPI === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
}
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

It is the first bundle of this project, I have also checked if the path was correct, and it is ok. Config files looks great, ISPConfig too. 
I do not know where to look.

Thanks !

Comment: For some reason you are using https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools and It is not configured properly (If you are using symfony ldaptools bundle see also: https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle)

Comment: Yeah maybe, but i don't know where in the bundle, I do not know which file is wrongly configured.

Comment: If your are using the *ldaptools-bundle* in your *app/config/config.yml* (see Getting Started here: github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle)

Comment: Thanks ! That's it !

Comment: But now I have other mistakes ^^
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ok, so I write an answer to for the records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using a https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools with https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle, so you need to provide a proper configuration in your **app/config/config.yml**

For more details check the **Getting Started** of: https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle

Answer (score 0):

first of all remove `if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['1xx.0.0.1','1xx.0.16.163','1xx.0.0.250','1xx.0.0.226','1xx.0.0.233','::1'], true) || PHP_SAPI === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}`

second
are you using a qualified domain name ? public accessible like domain.com ... domain.tld ... something ?

how did you setup your site ? ( i'm asking here cause i cannot comment )

did you setup your ISPconfig on your local machine ? or VPS ?

Comment: Ok, I have been remove the if, but nothing has changed. 
I defined the site name on ISPConfig, and in the local file on my computer, I redirected the domain name to the server IP (which works on another project).

Comment: why dont you use a subdomain ? if you dont have a dedicated domain, just signup for a free [subdomain](http://freedns.afraid.org/)
i really dont know what seems to be the problem

Comment: To put it simply, the ip address on which the site will be deployed, is currently that of the FTP server of the company. On the other hand on ISPConfig, I have many subdomains (one for the test site that I use at the moment, and another where the final version will be deployed)